почему ломается jupyter notebook после конвертации модели из Tensorflow в Tensorflow lite?
Мне нужно из модели Tensorflow получить модель Tensorflow lite. Но при попытке конвертации jupyter notebook постоянно перезагружался, чтобы я не делал. Тогда я подумал что всё дело в размере модели и решил сделать крошечную модель для теста. Тоже самое. Вот код конвертации:

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

После него юпитер ломается. Может кто подсказать что делать?
